# Rxjs create an observable that emits when a function is called

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm likely missing something simple but can't quite puzzle this out from the docs. I'd simply like to have a function that when called will emit a value on an rxjs observable.

Psuedocode:

```
const myFunction = () => true //or whatever value
const myObservable = ... emit true whenever myFunction is called

...use myFunction somewhere where it being called is a useful event so 
observers of myObservable can process it
```

What's the standard pattern to emit a value when a function is called with rxjs?

Comment: [bindCallback](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindCallback) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `Subject` for that https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects

Here is the reworked example from the documentation:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

const myObservable = new Subject<number>();

const myFunction = () => {
  subject.next(1);
  subject.next(2);
}

myObservable.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log(`observerA: ${v}`)
});
myObservable.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log(`observerB: ${v}`)
});

// ...use myFunction somewhere where it being called is a useful event so 
myFunction();
```

Normally, you don't even need `myFunction`. Calling `subject.next()` would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Subject`.

```js
const subject = new Subject(); // a subject to notify
const myObservable = subject.asObservable();

const myFunction = () => {
  subject.next(true);
};

myObservable.subscribe(console.log);

myFunction();
myFunction();
myFunction();
```